# False commit | Django

Tags: python, django, forms

My code is working as expected, but i would like to make some changes and I don't want to save the uploaded filename in SQLite database.

My code:

```
    # false commit to get upload file name
    upload = form.save(commit=False)
    upload.save()
    uploadFile = upload.file.name.split('/')[-1]
```

As I said, I don't want to save this form in database. So i comment out the line `upload.save()`, but the code is not working, displaying the below error message:

```
Exception Type: com_error
Exception Value: it's possible that the file may be removed, renamed or trashed.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the uploaded filename in your view then you can get it from request object directly like below:-

```
for filename, file in request.FILES.iteritems():
    name = request.FILES[filename].name
```